# RabbitMQ post install failiure

Tags: python, rabbitmq, salt-stack

We've upgraded RabbitMQ from version 3.2.1-1 To version 3.5.6-1.

```
In version 3.2.1-1:
We get these responses

    [root@]# rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
    Listing vhosts ...
    /
    /sensu
    ...done.
    [root@]# rabbitmqctl list_queues
    Listing queues ...
    ...done.
    [root@]# rabbitmqctl list_users
    Listing users ...
    guest   [administrator]
    sensu   [sensu]
    ...done.



    In version 3.5.6-1:
    we get these responses:

    [root@]# rabbitmqctl list_queues
    Listing queues ...
    [root@]# rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
    Listing vhosts ...
    /
    /sensu
    [root@]# rabbitmqctl list_users
    Listing users ...
    guest   [administrator]
    sensu   [sensu]
```

So "...done." was removed, however, the salt version we have now uses this module:
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/modules/rabbitmq.py

Which looks for  "...done." and omits it from the response. That’s the reason for postinstall errors (attached).
I’ve tried to fix python script and replace it, however, postinstall still fails.

Am I missing a step here? Why replacing the file with the fix didn’t solve the issue, do I need to restart some service after replacing the python script?
I’ve attached also the original and the fixed script.

Original:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Module to provide RabbitMQ compatibility to Salt.
Todo: A lot, need to add cluster support, logging, and minion configuration
data.
'''
from __future__ import absolute_import

# Import python libs
import json
import logging
import random
import string

# Import salt libs
import salt.utils
import salt.utils.itertools
import salt.ext.six as six
from salt.exceptions import SaltInvocationError
from salt.ext.six.moves import range
from salt.exceptions import CommandExecutionError

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def __virtual__():
    '''
    Verify RabbitMQ is installed.
    '''
    return salt.utils.which('rabbitmqctl') is not None


def _format_response(response, msg):
    error = 'RabbitMQ command failed: {0}'.format(response)
    if isinstance(response, dict):
        if response['retcode'] != 0:
            raise CommandExecutionError(error)
        else:
            msg = response['stdout']
    else:
        if 'Error' in response:
            raise CommandExecutionError(error)
    return {
        msg: response
    }


def _get_rabbitmq_plugin():
    '''
    Returns the rabbitmq-plugin command path if we're running an OS that
    doesn't put it in the standard /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin
    This works by taking the rabbitmq-server version and looking for where it
    seems to be hidden in /usr/lib.
    '''
    rabbitmq = salt.utils.which('rabbitmq-plugins')

    if rabbitmq is None:
        version = __salt__['pkg.version']('rabbitmq-server').split('-')[0]

        rabbitmq = ('/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-{0}'
                    '/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins').format(version)

    return rabbitmq


def _safe_output(line):
    '''
    Looks for rabbitmqctl warning, or general formatting, strings that aren't
    intended to be parsed as output.
    Returns a boolean whether the line can be parsed as rabbitmqctl output.
    '''
    return not any([
        line.startswith('Listing') and line.endswith('...'),
        '...done' in line,
        line.startswith('WARNING:')
    ])


def _strip_listing_to_done(output_list):
    '''
    Conditionally remove non-relevant first and last line,
    "Listing ..." - "...done".
    outputlist: rabbitmq command output split by newline
    return value: list, conditionally modified, may be empty.
    '''
    return [line for line in output_list if _safe_output(line)]


def _output_to_dict(cmdoutput, values_mapper=None):
    '''
    Convert rabbitmqctl output to a dict of data
    cmdoutput: string output of rabbitmqctl commands
    values_mapper: function object to process the values part of each line
    '''
    ret = {}
    if values_mapper is None:
        values_mapper = lambda string: string.split('\t')

    # remove first and last line: Listing ... - ...done
    data_rows = _strip_listing_to_done(cmdoutput.splitlines())

    for row in data_rows:
        try:
            key, values = row.split('\t', 1)
        except ValueError:
            # If we have reached this far, we've hit an edge case where the row
            # only has one item: the key. The key doesn't have any values, so we
            # set it to an empty string to preserve rabbitmq reporting behavior.
            # e.g. A user's permission string for '/' is set to ['', '', ''],
            # Rabbitmq reports this only as '/' from the rabbitmqctl command.
            log.debug('Could not find any values for key \'{0}\'. '
                      'Setting to \'{0}\' to an empty string.'.format(row))
            ret[row] = ''
            continue
        ret[key] = values_mapper(values)
    return ret


def list_users(runas=None):
    '''
    Return a list of users based off of rabbitmqctl user_list.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_users
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_users'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    # func to get tags from string such as "[admin, monitoring]"
    func = lambda string: set([x.strip() for x in string[1:-1].split(',')])
    return _output_to_dict(res, func)


def list_vhosts(runas=None):
    '''
    Return a list of vhost based on rabbitmqctl list_vhosts.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_vhosts
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run']('rabbitmqctl list_vhosts -q',
                              runas=runas).splitlines()
    return res


def user_exists(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the user exists based on rabbitmqctl list_users.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.user_exists rabbit_user
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    user_list = list_users(runas=runas)
    log.debug(user_list)

    return name in user_list


def vhost_exists(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the vhost exists based on rabbitmqctl list_vhosts.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.vhost_exists rabbit_host
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return name in list_vhosts(runas=runas)


def add_user(name, password=None, runas=None):
    '''
    Add a rabbitMQ user via rabbitmqctl user_add <user> <password>

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.add_user rabbit_user password
    '''
    clear_pw = False

    if password is None:
        # Generate a random, temporary password. RabbitMQ requires one.
        clear_pw = True
        password = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(
            string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(15))

    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'add_user', name, password],
        output_loglevel='quiet',
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    if clear_pw:
        # Now, Clear the random password from the account, if necessary
        res2 = clear_password(name, runas)

        if 'Error' in res2:
            # Clearing the password failed. We should try to cleanup
            # and rerun and error.
            delete_user(name, runas)
            msg = 'Error'
            return _format_response(res2, msg)

    msg = 'Added'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def delete_user(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Deletes a user via rabbitmqctl delete_user.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.delete_user rabbit_user
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'delete_user', name],
        python_shell=False,
        runas=runas)
    msg = 'Deleted'

    return _format_response(res, msg)


def change_password(name, password, runas=None):
    '''
    Changes a user's password.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.change_password rabbit_user password
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'change_password', name, password],
        runas=runas,
        output_loglevel='quiet',
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Password Changed'

    return _format_response(res, msg)


def clear_password(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Removes a user's password.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.clear_password rabbit_user
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'clear_password', name],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Password Cleared'

    return _format_response(res, msg)


def check_password(name, password, runas=None):
    '''
    .. versionadded:: 2016.3.0

    Checks if a user's password is valid.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.check_password rabbit_user password
    '''
    # try to get the rabbitmq-version - adapted from _get_rabbitmq_plugin
    try:
        version = [int(i) for i in __salt__['pkg.version']('rabbitmq-server').split('-')[0].split('.')]
    except ValueError:
        version = (0, 0, 0)
    if len(version) < 3:
        version = (0, 0, 0)

    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()

    # rabbitmq introduced a native api to check a username and password in version 3.5.7.
    if tuple(version) >= (3, 5, 7):
        res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
            ['rabbitmqctl', 'authenticate_user', name, password],
            runas=runas,
            output_loglevel='quiet',
            python_shell=False)
        msg = 'password-check'
        return _format_response(res, msg)

    cmd = ('rabbit_auth_backend_internal:check_user_login'
        '(<<"{0}">>, [{{password, <<"{1}">>}}]).').format(
        name.replace('"', '\\"'),
        password.replace('"', '\\"'))

    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'eval', cmd],
        runas=runas,
        output_loglevel='quiet',
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'password-check'

    _response = _format_response(res, msg)
    _key = _response.keys()[0]

    if 'invalid credentials' in _response[_key]:
        return False

    return True


def add_vhost(vhost, runas=None):
    '''
    Adds a vhost via rabbitmqctl add_vhost.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq add_vhost '<vhost_name>'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'add_vhost', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    msg = 'Added'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def delete_vhost(vhost, runas=None):
    '''
    Deletes a vhost rabbitmqctl delete_vhost.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.delete_vhost '<vhost_name>'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'delete_vhost', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Deleted'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def set_permissions(vhost, user, conf='.*', write='.*', read='.*', runas=None):
    '''
    Sets permissions for vhost via rabbitmqctl set_permissions

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.set_permissions 'myvhost' 'myuser'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'set_permissions', '-p',
         vhost, user, conf, write, read],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Permissions Set'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def list_permissions(vhost, runas=None):
    '''
    Lists permissions for vhost via rabbitmqctl list_permissions

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_permissions '/myvhost'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_permissions', '-p', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    return _output_to_dict(res)


def list_user_permissions(name, runas=None):
    '''
    List permissions for a user via rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_user_permissions 'user'.
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_user_permissions', name],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    return _output_to_dict(res)


def set_user_tags(name, tags, runas=None):
    '''Add user tags via rabbitmqctl set_user_tags

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.set_user_tags 'myadmin' 'administrator'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()

    if tags and isinstance(tags, (list, tuple)):
        tags = ' '.join(tags)

    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'set_user_tags', name, tags],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = "Tag(s) set"
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def status(runas=None):
    '''
    return rabbitmq status

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.status
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'status'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    return res


def cluster_status(runas=None):
    '''
    return rabbitmq cluster_status

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.cluster_status
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'cluster_status'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    return res


def join_cluster(host, user='rabbit', ram_node=None, runas=None):
    '''
    Join a rabbit cluster

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.join_cluster 'rabbit.example.com' 'rabbit'
    '''
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'join_cluster']
    if ram_node:
        cmd.append('--ram')
    cmd.append('{0}@{1}'.format(user, host))

    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    stop_app(runas)
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    start_app(runas)

    return _format_response(res, 'Join')


def stop_app(runas=None):
    '''
    Stops the RabbitMQ application, leaving the Erlang node running.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.stop_app
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'stop_app'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def start_app(runas=None):
    '''
    Start the RabbitMQ application.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.start_app
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'start_app'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def reset(runas=None):
    '''
    Return a RabbitMQ node to its virgin state

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.reset
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'reset'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def force_reset(runas=None):
    '''
    Forcefully Return a RabbitMQ node to its virgin state

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.force_reset
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'force_reset'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def list_queues(runas=None, *args):
    '''
    Returns queue details of the / virtual host

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_queues messages consumers
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_queues']
    cmd.extend(args)
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)


def list_queues_vhost(vhost, runas=None, *args):
    '''
    Returns queue details of specified virtual host. This command will consider
    first parameter as the vhost name and rest will be treated as
    queueinfoitem. For getting details on vhost ``/``, use :mod:`list_queues
    <salt.modules.rabbitmq.list_queues>` instead).

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_queues messages consumers
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_queues', '-p', vhost]
    cmd.extend(args)
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)


def list_policies(vhost="/", runas=None):
    '''
    Return a dictionary of policies nested by vhost and name
    based on the data returned from rabbitmqctl list_policies.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_policies'
    '''
    ret = {}
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    output = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_policies', '-p', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    for line in salt.utils.itertools.split(output, '\n'):
        if '...' not in line:
            parts = line.split('\t')
            if len(parts) not in (5, 6):
                continue
            vhost, name = parts[0], parts[1]
            if vhost not in ret:
                ret[vhost] = {}
            ret[vhost][name] = {}
            # How many fields are there? - 'apply_to' was inserted in position
            # 2 at some point
            offset = len(parts) - 5
            if len(parts) == 6:
                ret[vhost][name]['apply_to'] = parts[2]
            ret[vhost][name].update({
                'pattern': parts[offset+2],
                'definition': parts[offset+3],
                'priority': parts[offset+4]
            })
    log.debug('Listing policies: {0}'.format(ret))
    return ret


def set_policy(vhost, name, pattern, definition, priority=None, runas=None):
    '''
    Set a policy based on rabbitmqctl set_policy.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.set_policy / HA '.*' '{"ha-mode":"all"}'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    if isinstance(definition, dict):
        definition = json.dumps(definition)
    if not isinstance(definition, six.string_types):
        raise SaltInvocationError(
            'The \'definition\' argument must be a dictionary or JSON string'
        )
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'set_policy', '-p', vhost]
    if priority:
        cmd.extend(['--priority', priority])
    cmd.extend([name, pattern, definition])
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    log.debug('Set policy: {0}'.format(res))
    return _format_response(res, 'Set')


def delete_policy(vhost, name, runas=None):
    '''
    Delete a policy based on rabbitmqctl clear_policy.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.delete_policy / HA'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'clear_policy', '-p', vhost, name],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    log.debug('Delete policy: {0}'.format(res))
    return _format_response(res, 'Deleted')


def policy_exists(vhost, name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the policy exists based on rabbitmqctl list_policies.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.policy_exists / HA
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    policies = list_policies(runas=runas)
    return bool(vhost in policies and name in policies[vhost])


def plugin_is_enabled(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the plugin is enabled.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.plugin_is_enabled foo
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = [_get_rabbitmq_plugin(), 'list', '-m', '-e']
    ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd, python_shell=False, runas=runas)
    if ret['retcode'] != 0:
        raise CommandExecutionError(
            'RabbitMQ command failed: {0}'.format(ret['stderr'])
        )
    return bool(name in ret['stdout'])


def enable_plugin(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Enable a RabbitMQ plugin via the rabbitmq-plugins command.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.enable_plugin foo
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = [_get_rabbitmq_plugin(), 'enable', name]
    ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    return _format_response(ret, 'Enabled')


def disable_plugin(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Disable a RabbitMQ plugin via the rabbitmq-plugins command.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.disable_plugin foo
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = [_get_rabbitmq_plugin(), 'disable', name]
    ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    return _format_response(ret, 'Disabled')
```

Fixed:

```
def _strip_listing_to_done(output_list):
    '''
    Conditionally remove non-relevant first and last line,
    "Listing ..." - "...done".
    outputlist: rabbitmq command output split by newline
    return value: list, conditionally modified, may be empty.
    '''

    # conditionally remove non-relevant first line
    f_line = ''.join(output_list[:1])
    if f_line.startswith('Listing') and f_line.endswith('...'):
        output_list.pop(0)

    # some versions of rabbitmq have no trailing '...done' line,
    # which some versions do not output.
    l_line = ''.join(output_list[-1:])
    if l_line == '...done':
        output_list.pop()

    return output_list
```

Here is the error i'm getting:

```
[user@ ]$ sudo rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_auth_backend_internal:check_user_login(<<"user">>, [{password, <<"password">>}]).'
Error: {undef,
           [{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,check_user_login,
                [<<"user">>,[{password,<<"password">>}]]},
            {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
            {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5}]}
```

Comment: Python 2.6? RLY?

Comment: this is what we use in our company, we can't upgrade it for now.

Comment: Didn't see the post install errors you mention, could you update your question with them? Also the original code you "fixed" actually does manage the lack of `...done` just fine, it rebuilds the output lines taking unwanted data (like done... and Listing... and WARNING) from the output it processes. So leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Module to provide RabbitMQ compatibility to Salt.
Todo: A lot, need to add cluster support, logging, and minion configuration
data.
'''
from __future__ import absolute_import

# Import python libs
import json
import logging
import random
import string

# Import salt libs
import salt.utils
import salt.utils.itertools
import salt.ext.six as six
from salt.exceptions import SaltInvocationError
from salt.ext.six.moves import range
from salt.exceptions import CommandExecutionError

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def __virtual__():
    '''
    Verify RabbitMQ is installed.
    '''
    return salt.utils.which('rabbitmqctl') is not None


def _format_response(response, msg):
    error = 'RabbitMQ command failed: {0}'.format(response)
    if isinstance(response, dict):
        if response['retcode'] != 0:
            raise CommandExecutionError(error)
        else:
            msg = response['stdout']
    else:
        if 'Error' in response:
            raise CommandExecutionError(error)
    return {
        msg: response
    }


def _get_rabbitmq_plugin():
    '''
    Returns the rabbitmq-plugin command path if we're running an OS that
    doesn't put it in the standard /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin
    This works by taking the rabbitmq-server version and looking for where it
    seems to be hidden in /usr/lib.
    '''
    rabbitmq = salt.utils.which('rabbitmq-plugins')

    if rabbitmq is None:
        version = __salt__['pkg.version']('rabbitmq-server').split('-')[0]

        rabbitmq = ('/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-{0}'
                    '/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins').format(version)

    return rabbitmq


def _safe_output(line):
    '''
    Looks for rabbitmqctl warning, or general formatting, strings that aren't
    intended to be parsed as output.
    Returns a boolean whether the line can be parsed as rabbitmqctl output.
    '''

    return not any([
        line.startswith('Listing') and line.endswith('...'),
        line.startswith('Listing') and '\t' not in line,
        '...done' in line,
        line.startswith('WARNING:')
    ])


def _strip_listing_to_done(output_list):
    '''
    Conditionally remove non-relevant first and last line,
    "Listing ..." - "...done".
    outputlist: rabbitmq command output split by newline
    return value: list, conditionally modified, may be empty.
    '''

    return [line for line in output_list if _safe_output(line)]


def _output_to_dict(cmdoutput, values_mapper=None):
    '''
    Convert rabbitmqctl output to a dict of data
    cmdoutput: string output of rabbitmqctl commands
    values_mapper: function object to process the values part of each line
    '''
    ret = {}
    if values_mapper is None:
        values_mapper = lambda string: string.split('\t')

    # remove first and last line: Listing ... - ...done
    # data_rows = _strip_listing_to_done(cmdoutput.splitlines())
    data_rows = cmdoutput.splitlines()

    for row in data_rows:
        try:
            key, values = row.split('\t', 1)
        except ValueError:
            # If we have reached this far, we've hit an edge case where the row
            # only has one item: the key. The key doesn't have any values, so we
            # set it to an empty string to preserve rabbitmq reporting behavior.
            # e.g. A user's permission string for '/' is set to ['', '', ''],
            # Rabbitmq reports this only as '/' from the rabbitmqctl command.
            log.debug('Could not find any values for key \'{0}\'. '
                      'Setting to \'{0}\' to an empty string.'.format(row))
            ret[row] = ''
            continue
        ret[key] = values_mapper(values)
    return ret


def list_users(runas=None):
    '''
    Return a list of users based off of rabbitmqctl user_list.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_users
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_users'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    # func to get tags from string such as "[admin, monitoring]"
    func = lambda string: set([x.strip() for x in string[1:-1].split(',')])
    return _output_to_dict(res, func)


def list_vhosts(runas=None):
    '''
    Return a list of vhost based on rabbitmqctl list_vhosts.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_vhosts
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run']('rabbitmqctl list_vhosts -q',
                              runas=runas).splitlines()
    return res


def user_exists(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the user exists based on rabbitmqctl list_users.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.user_exists rabbit_user
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    user_list = list_users(runas=runas)
    log.debug(user_list)

    return name in user_list


def vhost_exists(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the vhost exists based on rabbitmqctl list_vhosts.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.vhost_exists rabbit_host
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return name in list_vhosts(runas=runas)


def add_user(name, password=None, runas=None):
    '''
    Add a rabbitMQ user via rabbitmqctl user_add <user> <password>

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.add_user rabbit_user password
    '''
    clear_pw = False

    if password is None:
        # Generate a random, temporary password. RabbitMQ requires one.
        clear_pw = True
        password = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(
            string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(15))

    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'add_user', name, password],
        output_loglevel='quiet',
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    if clear_pw:
        # Now, Clear the random password from the account, if necessary
        res2 = clear_password(name, runas)

        if 'Error' in res2:
            # Clearing the password failed. We should try to cleanup
            # and rerun and error.
            delete_user(name, runas)
            msg = 'Error'
            return _format_response(res2, msg)

    msg = 'Added'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def delete_user(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Deletes a user via rabbitmqctl delete_user.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.delete_user rabbit_user
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'delete_user', name],
        python_shell=False,
        runas=runas)
    msg = 'Deleted'

    return _format_response(res, msg)


def change_password(name, password, runas=None):
    '''
    Changes a user's password.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.change_password rabbit_user password
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'change_password', name, password],
        runas=runas,
        output_loglevel='quiet',
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Password Changed'

    return _format_response(res, msg)


def clear_password(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Removes a user's password.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.clear_password rabbit_user
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'clear_password', name],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Password Cleared'

    return _format_response(res, msg)


def check_password(name, password, runas=None):
    '''
    .. versionadded:: 2016.3.0

    Checks if a user's password is valid.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.check_password rabbit_user password
    '''
    # try to get the rabbitmq-version - adapted from _get_rabbitmq_plugin
    try:
        version = [int(i) for i in __salt__['pkg.version']('rabbitmq-server').split('-')[0].split('.')]
    except ValueError:
        version = (0, 0, 0)
    if len(version) < 3:
        version = (0, 0, 0)

    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()

    # rabbitmq introduced a native api to check a username and password in version 3.5.7.
    if tuple(version) >= (3, 5, 7):
        res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
            ['rabbitmqctl', 'authenticate_user', name, password],
            runas=runas,
            output_loglevel='quiet',
            python_shell=False)
        msg = 'password-check'
        return _format_response(res, msg)

    cmd = ('rabbit_auth_backend_internal:user_login_authentication'
        '(<<"{0}">>, [{{password, <<"{1}">>}}]).').format(
        name.replace('"', '\\"'),
        password.replace('"', '\\"'))

    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'eval', cmd],
        runas=runas,
        output_loglevel='quiet',
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'password-check'

    _response = _format_response(res, msg)
    _key = _response.keys()[0]

    if 'invalid credentials' in _response[_key]:
        return False

    return True


def add_vhost(vhost, runas=None):
    '''
    Adds a vhost via rabbitmqctl add_vhost.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq add_vhost '<vhost_name>'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'add_vhost', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    msg = 'Added'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def delete_vhost(vhost, runas=None):
    '''
    Deletes a vhost rabbitmqctl delete_vhost.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.delete_vhost '<vhost_name>'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'delete_vhost', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Deleted'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def set_permissions(vhost, user, conf='.*', write='.*', read='.*', runas=None):
    '''
    Sets permissions for vhost via rabbitmqctl set_permissions

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.set_permissions 'myvhost' 'myuser'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'set_permissions', '-p',
         vhost, user, conf, write, read],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = 'Permissions Set'
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def list_permissions(vhost, runas=None):
    '''
    Lists permissions for vhost via rabbitmqctl list_permissions

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_permissions '/myvhost'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_permissions', '-p', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    return _output_to_dict(res)


def list_user_permissions(name, runas=None):
    '''
    List permissions for a user via rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_user_permissions 'user'.
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_user_permissions', name],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    return _output_to_dict(res)


def set_user_tags(name, tags, runas=None):
    '''Add user tags via rabbitmqctl set_user_tags

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.set_user_tags 'myadmin' 'administrator'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()

    if tags and isinstance(tags, (list, tuple)):
        tags = ' '.join(tags)

    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'set_user_tags', name, tags],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    msg = "Tag(s) set"
    return _format_response(res, msg)


def status(runas=None):
    '''
    return rabbitmq status

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.status
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'status'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    return res


def cluster_status(runas=None):
    '''
    return rabbitmq cluster_status

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.cluster_status
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'cluster_status'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)

    return res


def join_cluster(host, user='rabbit', ram_node=None, runas=None):
    '''
    Join a rabbit cluster

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.join_cluster 'rabbit.example.com' 'rabbit'
    '''
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'join_cluster']
    if ram_node:
        cmd.append('--ram')
    cmd.append('{0}@{1}'.format(user, host))

    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    stop_app(runas)
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    start_app(runas)

    return _format_response(res, 'Join')


def stop_app(runas=None):
    '''
    Stops the RabbitMQ application, leaving the Erlang node running.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.stop_app
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'stop_app'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def start_app(runas=None):
    '''
    Start the RabbitMQ application.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.start_app
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'start_app'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def reset(runas=None):
    '''
    Return a RabbitMQ node to its virgin state

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.reset
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'reset'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def force_reset(runas=None):
    '''
    Forcefully Return a RabbitMQ node to its virgin state

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.force_reset
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'force_reset'],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)


def list_queues(runas=None, *args):
    '''
    Returns queue details of the / virtual host

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_queues messages consumers
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_queues']
    cmd.extend(args)
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)


def list_queues_vhost(vhost, runas=None, *args):
    '''
    Returns queue details of specified virtual host. This command will consider
    first parameter as the vhost name and rest will be treated as
    queueinfoitem. For getting details on vhost ``/``, use :mod:`list_queues
    <salt.modules.rabbitmq.list_queues>` instead).

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_queues messages consumers
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_queues', '-p', vhost]
    cmd.extend(args)
    return __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)


def list_policies(vhost="/", runas=None):
    '''
    Return a dictionary of policies nested by vhost and name
    based on the data returned from rabbitmqctl list_policies.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.list_policies'
    '''
    ret = {}
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    output = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'list_policies', '-p', vhost],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    for line in salt.utils.itertools.split(output, '\n'):
        if '...' not in line:
            parts = line.split('\t')
            if len(parts) not in (5, 6):
                continue
            vhost, name = parts[0], parts[1]
            if vhost not in ret:
                ret[vhost] = {}
            ret[vhost][name] = {}
            # How many fields are there? - 'apply_to' was inserted in position
            # 2 at some point
            offset = len(parts) - 5
            if len(parts) == 6:
                ret[vhost][name]['apply_to'] = parts[2]
            ret[vhost][name].update({
                'pattern': parts[offset+2],
                'definition': parts[offset+3],
                'priority': parts[offset+4]
            })
    log.debug('Listing policies: {0}'.format(ret))
    return ret


def set_policy(vhost, name, pattern, definition, priority=None, runas=None):
    '''
    Set a policy based on rabbitmqctl set_policy.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.set_policy / HA '.*' '{"ha-mode":"all"}'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    if isinstance(definition, dict):
        definition = json.dumps(definition)
    if not isinstance(definition, six.string_types):
        raise SaltInvocationError(
            'The \'definition\' argument must be a dictionary or JSON string'
        )
    cmd = ['rabbitmqctl', 'set_policy', '-p', vhost]
    if priority:
        cmd.extend(['--priority', priority])
    cmd.extend([name, pattern, definition])
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    log.debug('Set policy: {0}'.format(res))
    return _format_response(res, 'Set')


def delete_policy(vhost, name, runas=None):
    '''
    Delete a policy based on rabbitmqctl clear_policy.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.delete_policy / HA'
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    res = __salt__['cmd.run'](
        ['rabbitmqctl', 'clear_policy', '-p', vhost, name],
        runas=runas,
        python_shell=False)
    log.debug('Delete policy: {0}'.format(res))
    return _format_response(res, 'Deleted')


def policy_exists(vhost, name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the policy exists based on rabbitmqctl list_policies.

    Reference: http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.policy_exists / HA
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    policies = list_policies(runas=runas)
    return bool(vhost in policies and name in policies[vhost])


def plugin_is_enabled(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Return whether the plugin is enabled.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.plugin_is_enabled foo
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = [_get_rabbitmq_plugin(), 'list', '-m', '-e']
    ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd, python_shell=False, runas=runas)
    if ret['retcode'] != 0:
        raise CommandExecutionError(
            'RabbitMQ command failed: {0}'.format(ret['stderr'])
        )
    return bool(name in ret['stdout'])


def enable_plugin(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Enable a RabbitMQ plugin via the rabbitmq-plugins command.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.enable_plugin foo
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = [_get_rabbitmq_plugin(), 'enable', name]
    ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    return _format_response(ret, 'Enabled')


def disable_plugin(name, runas=None):
    '''
    Disable a RabbitMQ plugin via the rabbitmq-plugins command.

    CLI Example:

    .. code-block:: bash

        salt '*' rabbitmq.disable_plugin foo
    '''
    if runas is None:
        runas = salt.utils.get_user()
    cmd = [_get_rabbitmq_plugin(), 'disable', name]
    ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd, runas=runas, python_shell=False)
    return _format_response(ret, 'Disabled')
```